# Automatically delete recordings

Tags: javascript, hotjar

I'm looking at automatically deleting recordings on my Hotjar account where videos are longer than 30 seconds, and where users land on a specific page.

There are Javascript triggers available, but there doesn't appear to be any Javascript trigger to automatically achieve this.

We're looking at only recording videos where they are shorter than 30 seconds.

Comment: I'm in the same boat and I'm starting to worry, as there are no answers to be found.